# JHipster:Relation "datcat_attribute_metadata" does not exist

Tags: jhipster

JHipster is not creating the table **DatcatAttributeMetadata** to the database. This is a child table with a foreign key relationship manyToOne with parent table DatcatAttributeMetadata.
Parent table was created earlier but when adding DatcatAttributeMetadata using Jhipster entity module this table is not being added to PostgresSql and throwing an error ERROR: relation "datcat_attribute_metadata" does not exist

Have tried --force-entity and mvn liquidbase:diff multiple times but still the table is not being created in DB

Below is the code snippet to

- master.xml
- 20170612191949_added_entity_constraints_DatcatAttributeMetadata.xml
- 20170612191949_added_entity_DatcatAttributeMetadata.xml

  http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

  ```
  <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/00000000000000_initial_schema.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
  <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170612161115_added_entity_DatcatDatasetMetadata.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
  <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170612191949_added_entity_DatcatAttributeMetadata.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
  <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase changelogs here -->
  <include file="classpath:config/liquibase/changelog/20170612191949_added_entity_constraints_DatcatAttributeMetadata.xml" relativeToChangelogFile="false"/>
  <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-constraints-changelog - JHipster will add liquibase constraints changelogs here -->
  ```

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <databaseChangeLog
      xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">
      <!--
          Added the constraints for entity DatcatAttributeMetadata.
      -->
      <changeSet id="20170612191949-2" author="jhipster">

          <addForeignKeyConstraint baseColumnNames="dataset_id_id"
                                   baseTableName="datcat_attribute_metadata"
                                   constraintName="fk_datcat_attribute_metadata_dataset_id_id"
                                   referencedColumnNames="dataset_id"
                                   referencedTableName="datcat_dataset_metadata"/>

      </changeSet>
  </databaseChangeLog>
  ```

  http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd
                          http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">

  ```
  <property name="now" value="now()" dbms="h2"/>

  <property name="now" value="current_timestamp" dbms="postgresql"/>

  <property name="floatType" value="float4" dbms="postgresql, h2"/>
  <property name="floatType" value="float" dbms="mysql, oracle, mssql"/>


  <changeSet id="20170612191949-1" author="jhipster">
      <createTable tableName="datcat_attribute_metadata">
          <column name="attribute_id" type="bigint" autoIncrement="${autoIncrement}">
              <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false"/>
          </column>
          <column name="attribute_def" type="varchar(255)">
              <constraints nullable="false" />
          </column>

          <column name="primary_key" type="boolean">
              <constraints nullable="false" />
          </column>

          <column name="foreign_key" type="varchar(255)">
              <constraints nullable="true" />
          </column>

          <column name="attribute_datatype" type="varchar(255)">
              <constraints nullable="false" />
          </column>

          <column name="attribute_lenght" type="integer">
              <constraints nullable="true" />
          </column>

          <column name="dataset_id_id" type="bigint">
              <constraints nullable="false" />
          </column>

          <!-- jhipster-needle-liquibase-add-column - JHipster will add columns here, do not remove-->
      </createTable>

  </changeSet>
  ```

**Logs**

```
2017-06-12 16:15:01.198 DEBUG 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] c.e.p.d.apis.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Enter: com.exelon.predix.datacatalog.apis.web.rest.DatcatAttributeMetadataResource.getAllDatcatAttributeMetadata() with argument[s] = [Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: id: ASC]]
2017-06-12 16:15:01.207 DEBUG 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] .d.a.w.r.DatcatAttributeMetadataResource : REST request to get a page of DatcatAttributeMetadata
2017-06-12 16:15:01.210 DEBUG 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] c.e.p.d.apis.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Enter: com.exelon.predix.datacatalog.apis.service.DatcatAttributeMetadataService.findAll() with argument[s] = [Page request [number: 0, size 20, sort: id: ASC]]
2017-06-12 16:15:01.210 DEBUG 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] a.s.i.DatcatAttributeMetadataServiceImpl : Request to get all DatcatAttributeMetadata
Hibernate: select datcatattr0_.attribute_id as attribut1_0_, datcatattr0_.attribute_datatype as attribut2_0_, datcatattr0_.attribute_def as attribut3_0_, datcatattr0_.attribute_lenght as attribut4_0_, datcatattr0_.dataset_id_dataset_id as dataset_7_0_, datcatattr0_.foreign_key as foreign_5_0_, datcatattr0_.primary_key as primary_6_0_ from datcat_attribute_metadata datcatattr0_ order by datcatattr0_.attribute_id asc limit ?
2017-06-12 16:15:01.223  WARN 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2017-06-12 16:15:01.223 ERROR 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "datcat_attribute_metadata" does not exist
  Position: 331
2017-06-12 16:15:01.237 ERROR 44521 --- [  XNIO-2 task-3] c.e.p.d.apis.aop.logging.LoggingAspect   : Exception in com.exelon.predix.datacatalog.apis.service.DatcatAttributeMetadataService.findAll() with cause = 'org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet' and exception = 'could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet'
```

Please not I have updated the column names of the primary key in both parent and child table as dataset_id and attribute_id respectively by making changes in liquidbase file and using @Column annotation in domain class.

Comment: You should post your log file of aoo startup, it may show you what liquibase is doing or not doing. Have you changed some generated changelogs and did  not re-create your database or did not reste liquibase checksums?

Comment: I have updated the logs in the original post